# Deploy Angular 2 'Quick Start' Example On Azure

Tags: angular, azure

It is the official example of Angular 2, here is the [repo](https://github.com/angular/quickstart).
I followed the instructions: [Visual Studio 2015 QuickStart](https://angular.io/guide/visual-studio-2015), to set up.

Added my stuff, ran it locally, so far so good. So, I moved on, just deployed the project on to Azure in the way as normally I deploy ASP.NET project, well, it is an empty ASP.NET project in fact. And I ran `npm install` in the console on Azure:
[image]

It looks like the packages are installed.

After the deployment, I have to go to domain.azure.net/src/index.html manually, and it cannot load the .js files, seems that they are forbidden, as the src/index.html is returned:

[image]

How can I make it work? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably thought too much, actually, when we are mindful that all of those complicated configurations have nothing to do with deployment, it is not difficult to find out a solution. Once we are done with all the transpilation, it is just about simple HTML and JavaScript.

I took two actions to make it work:

1. remove the base tag from the index.html;
2. let's say the root dir of your app service on Azure is `D:\home\site\wwwroot\`, then move the files and folders under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\src\` to `D:\home\site\wwwroot\`

I wrote down more details in my [blog](https://zlxadhkust.wordpress.com/2017/07/22/deploy-angular-2-quick-start-example-on-azure/).

The next problem is that you need to maintain a separate version of the src code for production deployment, and you also need to customise the deployment procedure. There are quite a lot task runners out there, but I am not sure what options we have in the case of Azure deployment.